# Forecast and 95% confidence interval

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics

I have this homework about time series econometrics and I am having some difficulty trying to solve it. Can somebody can help me understand how to start and solve it?

This is the text of the problem:

> Consider the process: $$y_t= 1.2y_{t-1} - 0.4y_{t-2} + x_t + u_t,\qquad t=1,2$$ where $y_0=0$, $u_t\sim N(0,16)$ is a white noise and $x_t$ is a stochastic process with known mean $μ_x=2$ and variance $σ^2=4$. Determine the forecast of $y_{t+1}$ and its 95% confidence interval (assuming normality) conditional on $y_t=1$ and $y_{t-1}=2$. State additional assumptions on $x_t$ if you need those.

---

*Update*:  I know how to determine the forecast of $y_{t+1}$ and I know the formula for the confidence interval, however, I get confused with those two conditions on $y_t=1$ and $y_{t-1}=2$. What do they mean in solving it? I do not want that some of you write the solution but I would like to understand how to solve it.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: You need to state  what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung I know how to determine the forecast of yt+1 and I know the formula for the confidence interval, however, I get confused with those two conditions on yt=1 and yt-1=2. What do they mean in solving it? I do not want that some of you write the solution but I would like to understand how to solve it. Thank you